# Google Apps Script: count occurences of string in HTML query

Tags: html, string, google-apps-script, count

I am trying to get the count of occurrences of a string in the text fetched from a website

```
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.larvalabs.com/cryptopunks/details/0000').getContentText();
  var offers = html.match('Offered');
  Logger.log(offers);
```

However I get the following data returned: [Offered]
I tried several methods but I do not find much documentation on those I can use to do this task that sounds simple.
I add that I tried to parse with XMLservice but some errors in the HTML code makes it fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, as one method, how about using `matchAll()`?

#### Modified script:

```
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.larvalabs.com/cryptopunks/details/0000').getContentText();
var offers = [...html.matchAll('Offered')];  // or [...html.matchAll(/Offered/g)]
Logger.log(offers.length);
```

- When I tested above, `3` is returned.

#### Note:

- In this case, the upper- and lowercase letters are distinguished. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)